# how to write regex to accept the string which end with string

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex which accepts this:

Accept:

```
done
done1
done1,done2,done3
```

Do not accept:

```
done1,
done1,done2,
```

I tried to write this regex

```
([a-zA-Z]+)?(/d)?(,)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

but it is not working.

What's wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does `[a-z0-9]$` helps?
It checks the last character in line, which means it will only match alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase the regex pattern as:

```regex
(?<!\S)\w+(?:,\w+)*(?!\S)
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = "done done1 done1,done2,done3 done1, done1,done2,"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?:,\w+)*(?!\S)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['done', 'done1', 'done1,done2,done3']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```regex
(?<!\S)    assert that what precedes is either whitespace or the start of the input
\w+        match a word
(?:,\w+)*  followed by comma another word, both zero or more times
(?!\S)     assert that what follows the final word is either whitespace
           or the end of the input
```

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on how you apply the regex. The regex alone (e.g. when used with `re.search()`) tells you whether the input contains any substring which matches your regex.  In the trivial case, if you are examining one line at a time, add start and end of line anchors around your regex to force it to match the entire line.

Also, of course, notice that the regex to match a single digit is `\d`, not `/d`.

Your regex looks like you want both the alphabetics and the numbers to be optional, but the group of alphabetics and numbers to be non-empty; is that correct?  One way to do that is to add a lookahead `(?=[a-zA-Z\d])` before the phrase which matches both optionally.

```py
import re

tests = """\
done
done1
done1,done2,done3
done1,
done1,done2,
"""

regex = re.compile(r'^(?=[a-zA-Z\d])[a-zA-Z]*\d?(?:,(?=[a-zA-Z\d])[a-zA-Z]*\d?)*$')

for line in tests.splitlines():
    match = regex.search(line)
    if match:
        print(line)
```

The individual phrases here should be easy to understand.  `[a-zA-Z]*` matches zero or more alphabetics, and `\d?` matches zero or one digits. We require one of those, followed by zero or more repetitions of a comma followed by a repeat of the first expression.

Perhaps also note that `[a-zA-Z\d]` is *almost* the same as `\w` (the latter also matches an underscore).  If you don't care about this inexactness, the expression could be simplified.  It would certainly be useful in the lookahead, where the regex after it will not match an underscore anyhow. But I've left in the more complex expression just to make the code easier to follow in relation to the original example.

Demo: https://ideone.com/4mVGDh